# Deprecated component cxfbean

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, spring-camel, cxfrs

I am new to camel and I am migrating camel 2.x app to camel 3.x.  I see that cxfbean scheme is deprecated and removed in version 3. I searched migration docs but I haven't seen anything related.

What is the best way to migrate where HelloService is just rest endpoint.

```
  <bean id="helloService" class="com.acme.HelloService"/>

  <camel:camelContext>
      <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="jetty:http://localhost:9000?matchOnUriPrefix=true"></camel:from>
        <camel:to uri="cxfbean://helloService"></camel:to>
      </camel:route>
  </camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I ended up with following steps

1. use "bean:youServiceBeanName" instead,
2. if your service has limited method, you can add ?methodname=xxx in the end if you want, like

   to( "bean:youServiceBeanName?methodname=xxx")

or if you have too many methods to map, you could set "CamelBeanMethodName" by processor of

```
    .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelBeanMethodName", exchange.getIn().getHeader("operationName")))
```

then camel will invoke the bean's method for you

3. about methods parameters, if camel can not map it correctly, you need to put @Header or @Body annotation on the rs service bean or interface method parameters,
4. if you want to have your own json mapper, in spring simply create a @bean of type ObjectMapper, camel will use that for marshal and unmarshal

make reference to [Bean::Apache camel 3](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/bean-component.html)